# Bettertouchtool: Able to assign new trigger to a key but could not deactivate actual real trigger

Tags: macos, applescript

Sorry, this question is for users of Bettertouchtool on Mac. I see some questions on SO posted using "applescript" tag.

With Apple keyboard, I would like to have access to F5 directly without pressing the "fn" key. Currently F5 serves as "mic key" and I assigned F5 using Bettertouchtool (in "key sequences"). However, pressing the key now triggers F5 function but also simultaneously activates "mic key". How to deactivate the intended purpose of the key? Thanks for any help.!